# CYGWIN, read command unrecognized

Tags: bash, shell, cygwin

I have installed *cygwin* and added *bin* folder to PATH. The problem is `read` command does not work as I use *cmd.exe*. What should I do about it? Which library should I install?

Comment: which shell are you running under? under `bash`, `read` is a builtin; please update the question with your sample `read` command and a description of what you mean by *`does not work`* (error? hangs? variable is not populated? something else?)

Comment: read should be a built-in.  No install necessary.  What do you mean by doesn't work?  Submit what doesn't work.  It is easier to then diagnose.

Comment: I run *cmd.exe*, type *read* and it says *'read' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or a batch file.*

Comment: `cmd.exe` starts up a windows command prompt/window  ... this is *NOT* how you start a `cywgin` session; when you installed `cygwin` it should have created a start menu item labelled `Cygwin` with an option of `cygwin64 terminal`; you may have also, optionally, installed a shortcut for `cygwin64 terminal` on your desktop; clicking on `cygwin64 terminal` should startup a `cygwin` session

Comment: ok, will give it a try. As thought it should all work in *cmd.exe* as I added *bin* to PATH

Comment: if you're referring to the Windows/OS `PATH` ... you shouldn't need to add anything to this particular `PATH`

Comment: You can invoke from CMD _executable programs_ (i.e. .EXE programs), Batchfiles, and files in a scripting language where you have an association to the file extension. `read` does not fall in any of these categories.

Answer (score 0):

`read` is built-in in Bash. If you look into the bin folder of Cygwin, there is no `read.exe`. Also even if you type `which read` in Cygwin, you will be told it is not in any PATH.

If you intentionally wanna to run `read` from Windows Command Prompt, run `bash --login -i` first to enter Bash session. Then you will be able to operation in command prompt same as in Cygwin. The Cygwin shortcut in start menu and desktop is essentially a batch script that will enter Bash session for you automatically from cmd.